# Why check the isBusy property of a BackgroundWorker dirrectly after constructor?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am currently maintaining some software written by another programmer

```
private void StartUpdate()
    {
        this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
        {
            // Set up the BackgroundWorker object by attaching event handlers
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(StartStepWorker);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(StepCompleted);
            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(StepProgressChanged);

            // Start the asynchronous operation
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

Is there any reason why, immediatly after creating the backgroundWorker, there is a check on the isBusy property? is there any reason why this is needed?
I assume that, since it was just created, the isBusy property will always be false? The RunWorkerAsync function is not used anywhere else in the code, so why checking?

I am afraid of removing the check, but can not think of any reason why it is there...
Can someone explain why he/she could have put this there?

Comment: It looks like when `StartUpdate` clicked a second time, it will forget the current worker and create a new one, which is a bigger problem.

Comment: The only thing that sets `IsBusy` to `true` is `RunWorkerAsync()`. Otherwise it starts off as `false`. [Source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs#L31). Sometimes when you look at old code, you have to remember it has potentially been through a journey. That is to say,  perhaps `this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();` didn't use to be there, so the check was necessary in case `StartUpdate()` was called a second time. Perhaps that was added, but the `if` statement was never removed.

Comment: As GSerg suggests, it seems worrying that the reassignment of `this.backgroundWorker` is there, since it creates a new one every time `StartUpdate()` is called.

Comment: Why are you using a BGW in the first place? That class is obsolete, fully replaced by `async/await`, `Task.Run` and `Progress<T>` since 2012

Comment: In this case you could change `void StartUpdate` to `async Task StartUpdate` and run whatever you want with `await Task.Run(()=>myMethod(param1,param2));` Check [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)